# Getting not a constractor error with javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify

Getting not a 'Shopify.CountryProvinceSelector' is not a constructor error message with javacript code. Maybe problem with creating object but I can't figure out what the happen? Below is my code

```
return _init = function() {
        new Shopify.CountryProvinceSelector("address_country", "address_province", {
            hideElement: "address_province_container"
        });
        var e = jQuery("#address_country"),
            t = jQuery("#address_province_label").get(0);
        "undefined" != typeof Countries && (Countries.updateProvinceLabel(e.val(), t), e.change(function() {
            Countries.updateProvinceLabel(e.val(), t)
        })), jQuery(".get-rates").click(function() {
            _disableButtons(), jQuery("#" + _config.wrapperId).empty().hide();
            var e = {};
            e.zip = jQuery("#address_zip").val() || "", e.country = jQuery("#address_country").val() || "", e.province = jQuery("#address_province").val() || "", _getCartShippingRatesForDestination(e)
        }), _config.customerIsLoggedIn && jQuery(".get-rates:eq(0)").trigger("click")
    },
```

Comment: Per [this page](https://help.shopify.com/themes/development/templates/customers-addresses) it appears to indeed be a constructor. We'll probably need to see more code (maybe a codepen?) to help.

Comment: Did you import all the right modules?

Comment: Yes, I added all the module and it's working perfectly but getting this message in console and creating a problem to another jquery element action. like opening a modal

Comment: @davidchappy you can visit the site https://epanouieskin.com and try to input the password to enter and then check the console

Comment: @AshikurRahman The enter password button is not firing the modal so I can't try it.

Comment: yes, this is the problem. the modal is not firing due to the error that I mentioned in my question. @davidchappy just check the console while the modal is not firing

Comment: @AshikurRahman I see that now. Something appears to have altered your main Shopify object. window.Shopify does not even define CountryProvinceSelector.